# Assignment and increment at the same time gives error, why?

Tags: javascript

I get Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation.
This is the code:

```
var visitNumber = parseInt("1")++;
```

Comment: That's just not syntactically meaningful. The right-hand expression is completely evaluated before the value of `visitNumber` can be set, and that expression makes no sense. The increment/decrement operators must operate on a valid reference to a variable or object property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't increment a number. You can increment the value of a variable. Add 1 and assign to the variable.

```js
var visitNumber = parseInt("1") + 1;

console.log(visitNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

The lefthand side for `++` must be a *variable*, it can't be anything else.

Either use this:

```
var visitNumber = parseInt("1") + 1;
```

or this:

```
var visitNumber = parseInt("1");
visitNumber++;
```

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt("1")` results in a constant, i.e. `1`, and you cannot change a constant. You need to assign it to a variable first (as @OriDrori mentioned in his answer), and then increment the variable.